# How to create shopping cart rule as buy X get Y free in Magento?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I would like to create a shopping cart rule as following:

"SO, WHEN YOU BUY 4 PACKS OF ARGAN BUTTER(SPECIFIC PRODUCT), YOU GET 4 PACKS OF ARGAN GEL(ANOTHER SPECIFIC PRODUCT) FREE."

I believe the best option would be the "buy X get Y free", however how to apply the conditions  for activating this rule?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the Shopping cart price rule Buy X get Y free (discount amount is Y), because as the name says, Y is the discount amount, not another product.

Instead, you can use Bundle products. You can create a bundle product containing 4 PACKS OF ARGAN BUTTER(SPECIFIC PRODUCT) and 4 PACKS OF ARGAN GEL(ANOTHER SPECIFIC PRODUCT), at the price of 4 PACKS OF ARGAN BUTTER(SPECIFIC PRODUCT).

You can find more info here: [Creating a Bundle Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product)